# Broken CSS on jQuery Mobile popup dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please see code at http://cyclestreets.darkgreener.com/location/ - if necessary, go to a London, UK location to see some markers)

When you click on a marker, a jQuery mobile dialog opens. However, the CSS is broken - it's against a black background.

(Compare the About and Prefs dialogs on the home page to see the correct CSS.)

It looks as though some of the dialog classes are not being applied to the content div.

Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery mobile dialogs appear against a black background because the parent page is removed from the DOM as soon as the transition completes.

You can get more standard looking dialogs with a couple of changes to the css and transition code:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/2380